# why stopping docker container doesn't closes the open port and how to close them?

Tags: docker, influxdb

I discovered that if we stop and remove the container

`sudo docker run -d --restart unless-stopped  --name=influxdb -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 -p "25826:25826/udp"  -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb`

the port are still open,

```
 sudo lsof -n -P | grep 25826
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
docker-pr 1340                 root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826 
docker-pr 1340 1349            root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826 
docker-pr 1340 1350            root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826 
docker-pr 1340 1354            root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826 
docker-pr 1340 1355            root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826 
docker-pr 1340 1358            root    4u     IPv6              24456      0t0        UDP *:25826
```

port `8083`

```
$ sudo lsof -n -P | grep 8083
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
docker-pr 1415                 root    4u     IPv6              25306      0t0        TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1415 1418            root    4u     IPv6              25306      0t0        TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1415 1419            root    4u     IPv6              25306      0t0        TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1415 1420            root    4u     IPv6              25306      0t0        TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1415 1421            root    4u     IPv6              25306      0t0        TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
```

and port 8086,

```
$ sudo lsof -n -P | grep 8086
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
docker-pr 1373                 root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1373 1374            root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1373 1375            root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1373 1376            root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1373 1380            root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1373 1383            root    4u     IPv6              25260      0t0        TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I observe the expected behavior: used while running; no longer used when stopped.

After running:

```sh
ss --listening --processes | egrep "(808[36])|(25826)" | wc --lines
3

docker container stop influxdb
influxdb

ss --listening --processes | egrep "(808[36])|(25826)" | wc --lines
0
```

Are you confident that you're correctly stopping the container?

Comment: I ran this command `$ sudo docker run -d --restart unless-stopped  --name=influxdb -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 -p "25826:25826/udp"  -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb -config influxdb.conf` and got error 
`8f118d0095c4ea4b1364889eabac3122c2c65e7f18310a071037a90aae328129
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint influxdb Bind for 0.0.0.0:25826 failed: port is already allocated.` then i ran your command expecting port should be open `ss --listening --processes | egrep "(808[36])|(25826)" | wc --lines` but i got  0

Comment: Curious. You should be able to grab the process for that port using `ss --udp --listening --processes | grep 25826` and then `ps -p [PID]`